# Displaying column statistics on map dynamically from layer table columns in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dynamic-text

I am looking for help to create a dynamic text box that will display statistics of columns for the layer tables. Example: In the map, there is a table that displays the premium information of insureds from a region. I have added labels that display per county premium. But I want to display the total premium somewhere on the map in a text box. It should be dynamic since the values will change in the next quarter.

What I tried:

1. In the layout view, insert dynamic text. But that is mostly related to the author or title or number of pages.
2. Use of labels. But that doesn't allow me to add dynamic text.

The format I would like to see:

"Total Premium: $ (some formula that adds premium column)"

A number should appear at the place of formula.

Is it possible in ArcMap?